# How to route specific client's traffic to VPN (PPTP)?

Tags: iptables, vpn, isc-dhcpd, pptp, bind9

The setup:

- I have a server set up as a DHCP (isc-dhcp-server) and DNS (bind9) server (acting as a router).
- It connects to the internet via pppoe (ppp0) using eth0 device.
- The eth1 is connected to a router acting as an access point.
- Through the access point clients can connect via ethernet or wifi.
- Traffic from eth1 is forwarded to ppp0 using iptables as defined here (with some modifications to match the internet device): https://killtacknine.com/building-an-ubuntu-16-04-router-part-3-firewalls/.
- IPV6 is also set up the same way.
- The ufw is also enabled with a "Anywhere ALLOW 192.168.1.0/24" rule.
- The server also connects to a VPN (PPTP) through ppp0, and when it is connected it gets the ppp1 as the device name.

What I would like to do is to forward a specific client's internet traffic (based on an IP or MAC address) that is connecting through the eth1 device to the VPN via ppp1.

I've tried to setup iptables with the following rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i ppp1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -s 192.168.1.113 -o ppp1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp1 -o eth1 -m conntrack  --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp1 -j MASQUERADE
```

But it doesn't seems to be working, I don't know what I'm missing, I have almost 0 knowledge with iptables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure your AP connected via eth1 **bridges** its own ethernet interface to the WLAN interface, otherwise DHCP will be useless, and if it does NAT (default with many home routers), you won't be able to see the IP address of the client.

2) You don't need `iptables` to do routing (a pet peeve of mine; for some reason, many people on the internet think they need firewall rules for routing...). In particular, you don't need to do NAT (unless your VPN requires it for some reason, but there's no information in the question to decide that).

If you want to *route* packets *from* a particular client, you need *policy routing* (google, there are many tutorials). Basically, you do

```
ip rule add from <source address> lookup <table name>
```

and then add a table that defines the routing, in your case, via `ppp1` and the gateway that's associated with it.

`ip route get <dest address>` will tell you where the OS thinks the packet should go. Much easier than to debug firewall rules.

3) Use `wireshark` (or `tcpdump`, in different windows, one for each network interface that is interesting) do debug everything. Without actually seeing which packets arrive where with what addresses, it's hard to tell what goes wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! The AP is just a "gateway" no dhcp enabled. Also for some reason ip rule get <dest address> doesn work, it says get is unkown. I'm using a ubuntu 16.04 server.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to set it up, I also had to run the "sudo ip route add default via <PPTP IP address> table vpn" command too, and it is now routing the traffic.

Comment: It's `ip route get ...`, sorry for the typo. Fixed in answer. Note that even if no DHCP is enabled, the AP WLAN interface must still be bridged to the LAN for DHCP on the server to work (DHCP is broadcast, which won't be routed). If the "gateway" configuration does that, then all good.